# How to break line in long showNotification for Rshiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am struggling to put a multi-line shiny notification in the middle of the page. However, none of the intuitive break-line commands like \r; \n or 
 do not work at all. I wonder what could be the workaround to deal with this?

Here is the minimal working example:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML(".shiny-notification { position:fixed; top: calc(300px);; left: calc(15px);; }" ))),

    textInput("txt", "Content", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
              sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
              Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut 
              aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in 
              voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur 
              sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt 
              mollit anim id est laborum."),

    radioButtons("duration", "Seconds before fading out",
                 choices = c("2", "5", "10", "Never"),
                 inline = TRUE
    ),
    radioButtons("type", "Type",
                 choices = c("default", "message", "warning", "error"),
                 inline = TRUE
    ),
    checkboxInput("close", "Close button?", TRUE),
    actionButton("show", "Show"),
    actionButton("remove", "Remove most recent")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    id <- NULL

    observeEvent(input$show, {
      if (input$duration == "Never")
        duration <- NA
      else 
        duration <- as.numeric(input$duration)

      type <- input$type
      if (is.null(type)) type <- NULL

      id <<- showNotification(
        input$txt,
        duration = duration, 
        closeButton = input$close,
        type = type
      )
    })

    observeEvent(input$remove, {
      removeNotification(id)
    })
  }
)
```

Your time and effort to answer this question is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My first thought was to wrap it in `HTML(...)`, with something like:

```
    HTML(paste(strwrap("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
              sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
              Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut 
              aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in 
              voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur 
              sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt 
              mollit anim id est laborum."), collapse="<br/>"))
```

That didn't work either. So I looked at the source for `showNotification`:

```
function (ui, action = NULL, duration = 5, closeButton = TRUE, 
    id = NULL, type = c("default", "message", "warning", "error"), 
    session = getDefaultReactiveDomain()) 
{
    if (is.null(id)) 
        id <- createUniqueId(8)
    res <- processDeps(ui, session)
    actionRes <- processDeps(action, session)
    session$sendNotification("show", list(html = res$html, action = actionRes$html, 
        deps = c(res$deps, actionRes$deps), duration = if (!is.null(duration)) duration * 
            1000, closeButton = closeButton, id = id, type = match.arg(type)))
    id
}
```

When you debug this, you see that:

```
> res
$html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. &lt;br/&gt; Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. &lt;br/&gt; Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

$deps
list()
```

One problem (I'm inferring) is that it is not trusting the string, so it is HTML-encoding everything (I do not know if or why that's the case, though I do suggest that allowing a user-defined message to be used within a notification might be suspect, along the same lines as sql-injection). So it might be possible to rewrite the function, ensuring the text is not escaped.

```
showNotification2 <- function (ui, action = NULL, duration = 5, closeButton = TRUE, 
    id = NULL, type = c("default", "message", "warning", "error"), 
    session = shiny:::getDefaultReactiveDomain()) {
    if (is.null(id)) 
        id <- shiny:::createUniqueId(8)
    res <- shiny:::processDeps(HTML(ui), session)
    actionRes <- shiny:::processDeps(action, session)
    session$sendNotification("show", list(html = res$html, action = actionRes$html, 
        deps = c(res$deps, actionRes$deps), duration = if (!is.null(duration)) duration * 
            1000, closeButton = closeButton, id = id, type = match.arg(type)))
    id
}
```

Several of the functions are not exported by `shiny`, so this is absolutely subject to the API changing and everything breaking. Or maybe this behavior is a bug and my rewrite here will be taken as the new version of it. Who knows.

When you use this function instead, things work as you might hope.

[image]

With this new function, you actually don't need `HTML()`, which may indicate a short-coming in this hack-implementation.

Comment: voted up since 
HTML(paste(err_message_vector,collapse = "<br/>")) 
worked for me